# Is it possible to register V2.0 apps that are not web apps?

Tags: support, registration, oauth2

I want to register an app that will use the V2.0 API here: https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register. However, the app will run on a mobile phone so I cannot enter a domain name.

What can I possibly do? Enter a fake domain name?

Answer (score 4):

You can register apps that aren't web apps.

This page: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication, gives details for registering a Desktop Application. A mobile phone app comes under the category of a desktop application.

You should use the implicit flow, so check the box at the bottom of registration form, and for  the OAuth domain use: `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` (note the lack of https://).

This is also the value you should use for the redirect_uri parameter (although with the https://). Then in your app you need to check for when the web browser loads stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success page.

It probably should be clearer on the registration page.

Comment: Also, if you're developing on Windows Phone 7 you're likely screwed since the WebBrowser control eats everything after a `#` in the URL.

Comment: @AnnaLear, I don't know about Windows Phone, but I do think the hash is a bit "flimsy", and it could be passed in a better way.